# Angular material mat-slider not working properly with Hammer.js

Tags: angular, angular-material, hammer.js

I was stuck on this for a while so sharing this (as actively encouraged on SO) in case others are facing the same problem.

**The problem**

In Angular when a custom **Hammer.js** config is created to prevent it blocking vertical page scroll and you are using **Angular Material** **mat-slider**, you might find the slider action not work smoothly, or allow the slider to be dragged.

If similar to me, you followed suggestions online, you probably created a custom Hammer config in **app.module.ts** like this:

```
export class MyHammerConfig extends HammerGestureConfig {
  buildHammer(element: HTMLElement) {
    const mc = new Hammer(element, {
    touchAction: 'pan-y'
  });

  return mc;
 }
}
```

With the provider declaration:

```
{provide: HAMMER_GESTURE_CONFIG, useClass: MyHammerConfig}
```

The above config ensures  only horizontal swipes are handled by Hammer, allowing vertical swipe events to reach the browser to scroll the page up and down.
However, if you happen to use the Angular Material mat-slider then the custom Hammer config class can cause issues with the slider action.

As mentioned earlier I will answer my own question below.

Versions used:
Angular **8.0.0**
Angular Material **8.0.0**

Answer (score 2):

To fix the problem with Angular Material **mat-slider** when a custom Hammer config is used, you simply extend from the **GestureConfig** class from "angular/material" instead of HammerGestureConfig:

```
import { GestureConfig } from '@angular/material';

export class MyHammerConfig extends GestureConfig  {
  buildHammer(element: HTMLElement) {
    return new GestureConfig({touchAction: 'pan-y'}).buildHammer(element);
  }
}
```

This should sort the slider problem.

Credit to post in Github:
https://github.com/angular/components/issues/4278#issuecomment-399572805